# SQL SELECT statement inside of FROM, with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I am writing a stored procedure, inside of which I have some variables and a temp table.

I am trying to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO table1(
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
SELECT
    @col1,
    t2.col2,
    t3.col3
FROM
    #table2 t2, 
         (SELECT * 
          FROM table4 t4 
          INNER JOIN #table2 t2 ON t4.ID = t2.ID) t3
```

However, say `t2` and `t3` have 5 rows, the above is inserting 5*5=25 rows, where it should just be 5. It seems like a cross product is being computed in the `FROM` between `t2` and `t3`, and I can't quite nail down why.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a join condition specified between t2 and t3

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking. So I need to join `t2` and `t3` inside of the `FROM`?

Comment: Something like: `from #table2 t2 inner join (select... ) t3 on t2.[field] = t3.[field]` . I don't know the common field(s) between t2 and t3.

Comment: Looks like you could eliminate the inline view (the `SELECT` inside the outer `FROM`) and just join directly:  `SELECT @col1, t2.col2, t4.col3 from #table2 as T2 join Table4 as T4 on t4.id = t2.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you intend to do?

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT @col1, t2.col2, t3.col3
    FROM table4 t4 INNER JOIN
         #table2 t2
         ON t4.ID = t2.ID;
```

Your original query has an extra reference to `#table2`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you should be using a comma instead of an actual join there?  That's probably what's causing a cross-product rather than a selection from joined rows.